# How to connect python to Oracle Application Express

Tags: python, oracle-apex

I would like to have some help with the parameters passed under the connection string through a .py file trying connection to my Oracle Apex workspace database:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("user", "password", "dbhost.example.com/dbinstance", encoding="UTF-8")
```

On the login page at "apex.oracle.com", we have to pass the following information:

[image]

Can I assume that the "user" parameter is equal to the USERNAME info, the "password" parameter is equal to the PASSWORD info and the "dbinstance" parameter is equal to the WORKSPACE info?

And what about the hostname? What is it expected as parameter? How do I find it?

Thank you very much for any support.

Comment: What are you expecting to see when you connect Python to an APEX database?

Comment: APEX is a development platform that runs on the Oracle database; perhaps what you are after is how to connect to the Oracle database from your python program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those parameters are not equivalent. An APEX workspace is a logical construct that exists only within APEX; it does not correspond to a physical database instance. Username and password do not necessarily correspond to database users, as APEX is capable of multiple methods of authentication.

APEX itself runs entirely within a single physical database. An APEX instance supports multiple logical workspaces, each of which may have its own independent APEX user accounts that often (usually) do not correspond to database users at all. APEX-based apps may have entirely separate authentication methods of their own, too, and generally do not use the same users defined for the APEX workspaces.

When an APEX application *does* connect to a database to run, it connects as a proxy user using an otherwise unprivileged database account like APEX_PUBLIC_USER.

If you want to connect Python to APEX, you would have to connect like you would any other web app: through the URL using whatever credentials are appropriate to the user interface and then parsing the HTML output, or through an APEX/ORDS REST API (that you would have to first build and deploy).

If you want to connect to the database behind APEX, then you would need an appropriately provisioned database (not APEX) account, credentials and connectivity information provided by the database administrator.